# How to use multiple database connections in the same \DB::statement()

Tags: jquery, laravel, generator

I'm trying to build a Laravel console command to copy the table schema from a remote database and create the table in my local database. Effectively, just to copy and paste the table.

I have multiple database connections set up already in `config/database.php` and I use this in other parts of the projects, e.g. for model connections etc. That side of it is all fine.

I know I can do `\DB::connection('connection_name')` to specify the connection for that query, but I need to work across two connections at the same time.

I've tried putting this in in various places in the code, but I haven't been able to make it work.

Below is the function that gets called. First we drop the local table, then recreate it with the schema from the remote database. That's the bit I'm stuck on - how to get the query to look at the remote table.

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->table = $this->argument('table');

     //drop the local table first
        \DB::statement('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' . $this->table . ';');

        \DB::statement('CREATE TABLE ' . $this->table . ' LIKE        ??remote_db_connection??.'. $this->table . ';');
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do `SHOW CREATE TABLE $this->table` on the external connection, and execute the resulting schema query on your main connection?

Comment: You're trying to do too much in one go. DB statement is just running raw SQL so if you cannot do it normally (in GUI for example) you wont be able to do it in `DB::statement`. You probably want to get the database structure in one go and then replicate that later.

Comment: Thank you ceejayoz, that pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this way, using connection method , you have to manually declare the connection if different from default,

```
DB::connection('pgsql')->statement('your statement here...');
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand OP's question. They want to do basically `CREATE TABLE foo LIKE remote_connection.foo`. Two connections in a *single* query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ceejayoz pointing me in the right direction - here is what i have which now works, although i sure this can be improved:

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->table = $this->argument('table');

    \DB::statement('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' . $this->table . ';');

    $stmt = \DB::connection('remote')->select('SHOW CREATE TABLE ' . $this->table);

    $stmt = ((array) $stmt[0]);

    \DB::statement($stmt['Create Table']);

}
```